# Preventing deletion of an object

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I have a class I know I can 'protect' certain attributes by making use of the `@property` and `@attr.deleter` decorators like this:

```py
class Foo: 
    def __init__(self):
        self._attr = True

    @property
    def attr(self):
        return self._attr

    @attr.deleter(self):
        assert self.attr != False
```

I am unable to find out how to 'protect' the `Foo` object itself from being deleted, however. I've tried raising an exception in an overridden `Foo.__del__`, but I get the following printed to sys.stderr instead:
`Exception ignored in: <function Foo.__del__ at 0x...>`

Of course, the object still gets deleted. How would I go about preventing deletion of an object instead?

P.S.: Normally I wouldn't try to 'protect' an object like this - it seems like bad practice to me. However, it was a *python programming course* which instructed me to prevent deletion of an object. If they try to learn it to new programmers, there has to be a way to do it, right?

Comment: Now you just prevent deletion of the `attr` attribute of your `Foo` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make sure there's always a reference to the object, it won't be deleted.  So I can imagine doing something like:

```
class Foo: 
    __all_foos = []

    def __init__(self):
        self.__all_foos.append(self)
```

so that there's a global list of all `Foo` objects which ensures that they will always have at least one reference.

Comment: While that will increase reference count, it does not fool the garbage collector which specifically looks for unreachable cycles: https://devguide.python.org/garbage_collector/

Comment: Trying to think how you'd go about deleting a class.  You could reassign something to that name, but wouldn't it still have a reference in the module's namespace?  That's a lot deeper into Python's garbage collector than I've ever cared to delve...

Comment: Note that in the above snippet, `__all_foos` is a class variable, not an instance variable!  A circular reference within the instance wouldn't fool the garbage collector, but if the class itself maintains references to its instances, they never become unreachable.

Comment: That certainly works! This way I can always get the `Foo`object again from `Foo._all_foos`.
I take it there is no way to save a specific reference to an object from being called with `del`?

Comment: Only if you owned that specific reference and could control access to it.  That'd be where your read-only attribute could come in handy.  You couldn't block the object from being removed from an arbitrary list that a caller had direct access to, though.